# Hazelcast SlowOperationDetector to identify operations with less than 1 sec execution time

Tags: java, hazelcast, distributed-caching, distributed-cache, hazelcast-imap

I have a performance use case by which I need to identify certain `process()` calls in the `EntryProcessor` which takes more than 300 milliseconds. I tried to make use of `SlowOperationDetector` with the following configuration.

```
    <!-- SlowOperation Detector Configuration -->
    <property name="hazelcast.slow.operation.detector.enabled">true</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.slow.operation.detector.stacktrace.logging.enabled">true</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.slow.operation.detector.log.purge.interval.seconds">60000</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.slow.operation.detector.log.retention.seconds">60000</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.slow.operation.detector.threshold.millis">300</property>
```

I have given a sample test code which sleeps for 1 second inside `process()`.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Config cfg = null;
    try {
        cfg = new FileSystemXmlConfig("C:\\workarea\\hazelcast\\hazelcast-perf.xml");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
    IMap<String, Employee> employeesMap = hazelcastInstance.getMap("anyMap");
    employeesMap.put("100", new Employee(100));
    SlowEntryProcessor slowEntryProcessor = new SlowEntryProcessor();
    employeesMap.executeOnKey("100", slowEntryProcessor);

}

static public class SlowEntryProcessor implements EntryProcessor<String, Employee>
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public EntryBackupProcessor<String, Employee> getBackupProcessor() 
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object process(Entry<String, Employee> arg0) 
    {
        System.out.println("About to sleep");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("done processing");
        return null;
    }

}
```

I don't get to see any logs when the configured threshold is less than 1000ms. So in this example, I don't see any slow operation stack trace or logs.

If I change the sleep time to 2 sec, and slow operation threshold to 1 sec, slow operation detector kicks in and logs are displayed.

Is this a bug in `SlowOperationDetector` or am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't a bug; but design. What we do is periodically scan the current executing operations. So it depends on the frequency of scanning. The slow operation detector isn't intended to be used (and therefor not designed) to detect such short operations. It is really intended for multi second operation execution.

Comment: hi peter, thanks for your help. Do you see any other way to achieve this using hz ? I have an entry processor which is getting called 10 times in a request. Due to higher number of calls ( which I cant reduce), even 300 ms becomes a big deal, as it totals to ~ 3 sec.
In general, how do you analyze hazelcast EP performance ?